# ASP.NET 5 tests on team city xunit.runner.dnx

Tags: asp.net, teamcity, xunit, dnx

I am using ASP.NET 5 and dnx with TeamCity. I have a unit test project and its run using a Powershell script that uses xunit.runner.dnx

It all works fine locally in visual studio and in Powershell, but when I move it to team city I get errors when it attempt to run the tests.

This is the error...

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Xunit.Runner.Dnx.Program..ctor(IServiceProvider services)
```

The error is not very helpful.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Are you sure  you are using the right version of xUnit? I have seen this when I ran my tests on RC1 runtime but used an older xUnit version. Here is the table that shows xUnit versions: https://github.com/xunit/xunit. For dnx RC1 use rc1 version of xUnit.

Comment: Thanks!. Yes, we upgraded the dnx version to rc1 on the build server but never restarted the build agents so it was using beta8 instead of rc1. All fixed now after restarting the build agents!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the version of xUnit does not match the version of dnx. If you moved to ASP.NET 5 RC1 you need to move to the RC1 version of xUnit.